# Does GeoPoint only accept maximum 6 digits after the decimal separator?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

For GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6)); does it mean GeoPoint only accepts maximum 6 digits after the decimal separator, and cut off from there?

I.e. for two coordinates "-1.1840760,52.9519040,0" and "-1.1840769,52.9519049,0", the GeoPoint on the phone will treat them as the same, as one point?

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates you have quoted are in an invalid format. They seem to be a mix of degrees/minutes/seconds and decimal degrees.

If the coordinate is in DMS then the degrees and minutes must be integers - only the seconds can have a fractional part.

To answer your question directly, the granularity of the lat and lon is 1 microdegree, or one millionth of a degree. Thus the best resolution you will get is 1 microdegree. This corresponds to distance of about 11 or 12 centimetres on a great circle, which is far better accuracy than you will ever get from a civilian GPS system.